# Why doesn't repeated Mantaux testing for Mycobacterium tuberculosis cause an immune response?

Tags: immunology, tuberculosis

I have never had TB but have had multiple TB tests for work. All negative. If you are introducing TB antigen with each test, why isn't a memory of that formed by the adaptive immune system?

Comment: It's an interesting question; I've had PPDs yearly for decades. May I ask what you found when you tried to answer this question with a search? Please edit your findings into you question and refine your question accordingly. Thanks!